# visual studio nmake copy command filed with exit code 1

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, nmake

In my Build Command Line for a NMAKE visual studio project I have this:

```
NMake /NOLOGO /R /F ...
copy D:\myfile $(outdir)..\..\mynewfile.txt
```

Both of these files exist in the specified locations but i get the following build error:

```
2>  The system cannot find the file specified.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\...\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(37,5): error MSB3073: The command "NMake /NOLOGO /R ...
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\...\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(37,5): error MSB3073: copy D:\myfile ..\..\mynewfile.txt" exited with code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A copy command in the visual studio build command line must always have quotation marks regardless of the path (ie. whether it has spaces or not). The command needs to be:

```
copy "D:\myfile" "$(outdir)..\..\mynewfile.txt"
```